# Why not "have too much available credit" on your credit card?

Tags: credit-card, canada

[*A Canadian's Guide to Money-Smart Living*](https://www.amazon.ca/Canadians-Guide-Money-Smart-Living/dp/1770865500/ref=sr_1_1?qid=1562486919&refinements=p_27%3AKelley+Keehn&s=books&sr=1-1)  (2019) by [Kelley Keehn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/kelley-keehn-9833744/?originalSubdomain=ca).  [I don't know  her degrees or qualifications.](http://www.goldengirlfinance.com/author/kelley-keehn/)

I first read this on p 94, but it looks like the same as p. 98 in  2015 edition that you can download.

> [image]

See point 4. Don't the rich have towering credit limits for their [platinum cards](https://www.businessinsider.com/the-5-best-credit-cards-for-the-wealthy-2013-7#2-jpmorgan-palladium-4)?

Is Keehn right to advise having a low credit limit? But she doesn't say how much is "too much".

Comment: It would be nice to know just how much is too much.  Currently all my cards (remember when they were giving you money to sign up?) add up to something over $100K, yet I seldom have monthly balances over $1K (always paid off), yet last I looked my credit score was well north of 800.

Answer (score 6):

In the US, at least, that **WAS** true, but doesn't seem so anymore.

https://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/will-increased-credit-limit-hurt-mortgage-approval-process.php

> You’re not alone in thinking that a credit limit increase can hurt your score and make it harder to get a mortgage. **Years ago, the common wisdom was** that the more credit you had available, the riskier the borrower.
>
> However, **the major credit scoring models don’t see it that way anymore.** In fact, the effect is almost the opposite. Current scoring models give you a higher score for using a small (or zero) percentage of your available credit, and the more credit you have available across both individual cards and all your cards together, the smaller your credit utilization ratio.

Comment: Aligns with my understanding except the part about having a zero balance. All other advice I've seen suggests 1% usage is better than none at all.

Answer (score 2):

> **Is Keehn right to advise having a low credit limit? But she doesn't
>   say how much is "too much".**

Most everything I read suggests that FICO in US or Canada does not penalize for too much available credit.
According to this [Experian Q&A](https://www.experian.com/blogs/ask-experian/how-much-available-credit-should-i-have/):

> From the standpoint of increasing your credit scores, you can't have
>   too much available credit.

The obvious caveat being that some people lack self control and will overspend if they have more credit available.

This Q&A on [creditcards.com](https://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/myth-too-much-available-credit-hurts-mortgage-chances-1586.php) also indicates that there is no such thing as too much available credit:

> Once again, the scores not only don’t penalize you for how much
>   available credit you have, but higher amounts of available credit in
>   proportion to card balances tend to produce higher scores through
>   lower credit utilization (balance/limit ratio).

A common rule of thumb is that you should have available credit at least 5x your highest monthly statement balance for a given year, to keep utilization down in the 20% range. If you read myfico or other credit card forums you'll find many people who greatly exceed that number with no ill-effect. Anecdotally, my available credit is about 20x my max monthly statement balance and my credit score was in the 820's last I checked (US FICO goes to 850).

There are mortgage-focused credit scores that factor things a big differently, but it doesn't sound like they are commonly used. As far as I can tell the only reason to keep a low available credit is to minimize risk of overspending.

**Edit:**
I initially missed the country tag, while Canadian scores go to 900 instead of 850 these Canadian credit sites indicate that the scores are based on the same factors as US credit scores:

[debtcanada.ca - Credit Rating 101](https://www.debtcanada.ca/library/credit-rating-101)
[Birchwood Credit Solutions - Credit Score Ranges in Canada Explained](https://www.birchwoodcredit.com/blog/credit-score-ranges-canada/)

Every now and then I see someone suggest that too much available credit would be concerning for a lender, but I've yet to see any statistics that support the notion that people otherwise responsible with credit suddenly behave very differently when they have too much available credit.

Comment: Is FICO used in Canada and does it score the same way as it does in the US?

Comment: @FrazellThomas Ah, I missed the country tag. FICO is used in Canada, but not sure if it varies.

Comment: "Every now and then I see someone suggest that too much available credit would be concerning for a lender…" I would expect the opposite, if the lenders are rational—having credit and not spending it shows restraint and sufficient resources.

Comment: @Kevin Certainly, it's an out-dated notion that as far as I can tell was never supported by data.

Answer (score 0):

This is true for USA Vantage 3.0, but my FICO score seems to track my Vantage score, so it might be true for Canada.

The amount of available  credit needs to be high to get a  good score. And yes, this is counter intuitive.

In my case, my credit score was very good but I wanted it higher. I increased the available credit on one of my cards by $10,000. My score went up, slightly, but up.

I use an app on my iPhone to track this.

I currently have about $3,000 in credit card debt, using 7% of my available credit. Using 0-10% is the goal, according to the app, to be in the excellent category. This was why I increased the available credit. I had been in the Good category and wanted excellent.

Curiously, under the Improvement section of the app, it tells me:

> The Highest credit limit on your open credit accounts isn't high enough compared to people with similar credit profiles.

I find this absurd since I have over $40k in available credit. I would have be crazy to use even a fraction of that.

But that's what the credit score shows. It shows that you have credit and can use it responsibly.

You may consider getting such an app for your phone and seeing what advice it gives you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two very similar but sublty different questions here:

> Will having "too much" available credit **impact my credit score?**

versus,

> Will having "too much" available credit **impact my chances of being approved for a specific loan?**

Other answers have thoroughly, and correctly, covered the first question. Current popular models don't penalize based on available credit being too high, and if you're carrying a balance on the day your accounts are reported, **having a higher limit can actually be a benefit to your credit score** (since it'll mean a lower utilization rate for a given balance).

However, **there's risk in focusing too much on credit score** - especially for a large, long term loan like a mortgage. Although credit score is important in the loan approval process, for mortgages and other large, long-term loans, other factors become very important, too. Especially debt to income ratio - even if you have a very high credit score, a lender will not give you a mortgage if they don't think you have the cash flow to support it. If your debt to income ratio is already very high, and you have very high credit limits on credit card accounts, that can be reason for denial (or at least approval for a lower loan amount), despite a high credit score - compared to someone with the same credit score and same debt to income ratio, but lower limits on their credit cards. Of course, this won't be a factor for many people - if you're managing your finances well and not trying to borrow more than you can reasonably afford.